# R foreach not looping at all

Tags: r, domc, parallel-foreach

I'm having some trouble trying to combine the output of a `foreach` statement using the package `doMC` on Linux x64:

```
# I'm running 33 different models, one for each label
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)

labels = paste0('y', 1:33)
dataset = get.Data()
test.data = get.Test()

pred = foreach(yi = labels, .combine = cbind) %dopar% {

    # handle special case, don't need a model here
    if (yi == 'y14')
        y.pred = 0
    else {
        # fit model
        fit  = glm(y ~ ., data = data.frame(y = dataset[, yi], dataset[, -1]))
        # get predicted probabilities
        y.pred = predict(fit, test.data, type = 'response')
    }
    y.pred
}

# This gives me an error, saying pred is not a matrix
colnames(pred) = labels

`Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5",  : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions`
```

In fact, `pred` is a vector with the first prediction, so the other labels are not running at all. This is strange, because this works fine:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)
set.seed(1)
M = foreach(i = 1:4, .combine = cbind) %dopar% {runif(3)}
print(M)

      result.1  result.2   result.3   result.4
[1,] 0.1370338 0.1556492 0.12846072 0.24629143
[2,] 0.3940809 0.4537018 0.69545139 0.02654378
[3,] 0.6287515 0.2379316 0.02993252 0.17504858
```

PS.: `doSNOW()` gives the same error!
Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: When yi is "y14" you are returning 0 which is presumably shorter than the length returned when yi is not "y14". Try `rep(0, nrow(test.data))`

Comment: I wish that was the problem, but it's not. The yi variable never reaches y14 in this case. In this case `0` will be recycled.

Comment: What does it reach? [Actually you are right, the 0 should be repeated automatically, I just tested it myself.]. Why don't you try to not combine the results (ie return a list) and then look at the list returned and see if there are any funny-looking elements in there

Comment: Also noticed that you don't seem to be using yi at all in the foreach body, only in the if statement.. is that right?

Comment: Let me run some tests based on your tips, thanks! The `yi` is used, edited.

Comment: I removed `.combine = cbind`, it returns a list with the first prediction. So, the remaining labels are not running it seems.

Comment: in your first code block above after foreach(). what is the result of class(pred) or str(pred)?

Comment: what is in `dataset`? can you `dput(head(dataset))`

Comment: also, `dput(head(test.data))`

Comment: `pred` is the result of `predict()` for `y1`, the remaining labels are being skipped for some reason. The datasets are at https://www.kaggle.com/c/tradeshift-text-classification/data. Both train.csv and trainLabels.csv., but i guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: I tested your code on simulated data and it all worked fine: `dataset <- data.frame(lapply(1:33, function(i) runif(100)));
test.data <- data.frame(lapply(1:33, function(i) runif(100)));
names(dataset) <- labels;
names(test.data) <- labels;

pred <- foreach(yi = labels, .combine = cbind) %dopar% {
  
  if(yi == "y14") { 
    y.pred = 0 
  } else {
  fit <- glm( y ~ ., data = data.frame(y = dataset[,yi], dataset[,-1]))
  y.pred = predict(fit, test.data, type = 'response')
  }
  y.pred
};

colnames(pred) <- labels;
`

Comment: I did a similar test, and it works. But with the 'real' data it does not. I read in some place here on SO that a slow inner loop may cause problems, i 'll try to find the link and post it here.

Comment: therefore, to diagnose this problem any further, we need to know how to load the datasets.

Comment: I think it's memory related, when i limit the dataset size the problem doesn't happen. weird.